# Naked dig cannot reach servers, otherwise resolution works

Tags: arch-linux, dns, dig

I installed `dig` via `pacman -S bind` and it hangs when started as `dig`:

```
# dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.25 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

DNS resolution works, though:

```
# ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.214.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mad01s26-in-f174.1e100.net (216.58.214.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=2.76 ms
64 bytes from mad01s26-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.214.174): icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=2.91 ms

# dig @192.168.10.3 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.25 <<>> @192.168.10.3 google.com
(...)
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             180     IN      A       216.58.214.174

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.10.3#53(192.168.10.3)
;; WHEN: Sat Feb 05 21:12:14 CET 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

It seems that `dig` cannot make use of the local DNS configuration - is there something I should do in addition to just installing it?

EDIT: per the comments requests:

- I control the firewall and it is open out
- `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty, `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` has `DNS=192.168.10.3` and `FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.`1
- `dig google.com @8.8.8.8` gives the same result as above (with a different IP due to geolocalization)
- `traceroute -p 53 -n 8.8.8.8` goes through

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say that port 53 is allowed by your firewall into `192.168.10.3`, but not whatever system you tried the first `dig` on. It would also be good to know what is in `/etc/resolv.conf` and what happens when you try `dig google.com @8.8.8.8` and what happens when you try `traceroute -p 53 -n 8.8.8.8`. Please add to your question.

Comment: @Bib: done. Please note that this is Arch, I have numerous other systems that work just fine. I really suspect that there is a specific setting in Arch for dig (I just started to use Arch, as opposed to Linux I use since 1994)

Comment: @WoJ `/etc/resolv.conf` shouldn't be *empty*. With systemd-resolved, it should be a link to the systemd-resolved' stub resolv.conf somewhere in `/run/systemd`.

Comment: @muru: yes, I just found out too. Looks like Arch missed that part in setting up the resolution, I will file a bug

Comment: @WoJ it's in the docs: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-resolved#DNS

Comment: @muru: you are right, thanks for the link. I do not understand, though, why this is not set up by default as it breaks some programs (such as `dig ` and requires a manual update)

Comment: @muru: I updated my initial answer with your information, thanks again (BTW one of the reasons for me to switch to Arch was the top quality documentation)

Comment: I guess because most applications work OOTB, and then other packages like NetworkManager would have to mess around with symlinks in the post install scripts (systemd-resolved is part of the base install and always present, but people can freely install other network services).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arch `/etc/resolv.conf` is not simlinked to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` and `dig` uses the former.

```
# rm /etc/resolv.conf && ln -s  /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

solves the problem but this <del>seems to be a bug</del> is an Arch deliberate choice (see edit below) in how the resolution is set up in Arch (Ubuntu for instance provides a `/etc/resolv.conf` link).

**EDIT**: as [@muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) mentions in the comments, this is [documented](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-resolved#DNS) in Arch and the suggested solution is

```
ln -rfs  /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```